# TextArea loose focus when using scrollBar

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

When you create a TextArea, you can listen to its "focusedProperty".

But if the user touch the inner scrollBar of the TextArea (if it's too small), the focus of the TextArea is lost (since the scrollBar has the focus).

But as far as I am concerned, the TextArea is still having the focus because the scrollBar are part or the TextArea and there's even no way of accessing them.

How can I hack the textArea so that I would detect when the user is using the scrollBar? I want to hack/create a focusedProperty that will return true when the user is typing text or using the scrollBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the `Scene`'s `focusOwner` property, and create a `BooleanBinding` that is true if it is a descendant of the text area and false otherwise:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextAreaFocusTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 200).forEach(i -> textArea.appendText(" "));
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 80).forEach(i -> textArea.appendText("\nLine "+i));
        Label label = new Label();
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        VBox root = new VBox(10, textArea, textField, label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

        BooleanBinding focus = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
            for (Node n = scene.getFocusOwner(); n!= null ; n=n.getParent()) {
                if (n == textArea) return true ;
            }
            return false ;
        }, scene.focusOwnerProperty());

        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.when(focus).then("Focused").otherwise("Not Focused"));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to be sure, the CallBack will be called each time the scene focus owner will change right?

Comment: The value of the `BooleanBinding` (`focus`) will be recomputed each time the scene's focus owner changes. (Actually, that's not quite true, but it's effectively true...) If you register a listener with that `BooleanBinding`, then that listener will be invoked whenever its value changes. If you bind to that `BooleanBinding` (as I did with the label's text property in the example), then the property that's bound to it will be recomputed when its value changes.

Comment: See also my elaboration on James' answer that makes this work even if the scene changes, e.g. when setting up the bindings before `textArea` is added to the scene or (less likely) when `textArea` is moved between scenes.

Comment: @TomasMikula 's answer is nice: if you are in a controller's initialize method, for example, the text area won't have been added to a scene.

Comment: Allright thank you for your precision. In fact I put an InvalidationListener on it and it was not working. But I put a ChangeListener and then it worked because what I wanted was the returned value and not when the value was computed.
Thank you Tomas for your comment, in my case, the scene is already there but it sure can be useful when it's not

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation on @James_D's answer, in case you need to be able to obtain the `focus` binding from his answer without having a reference to the scene, e.g. if you need to set up the bindings before the text area is added to the scene, are implementing a library, or just want to have your code less entangled.

This solution uses the [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) library for convenient selection of nested property (selecting `focusOwnerProperty` from the `sceneProperty`).

```
public static Binding<Boolean> containsFocus(Node node) {
    return EasyBind.monadic(node.sceneProperty())
            .flatMap(Scene::focusOwnerProperty)
            .map(owner -> {
                for (Node n = owner; n != null; n = n.getParent()) {
                    if (n == node) return true ;
                }
                return false ;
            })
            .orElse(false); // when node.getScene() is null
}
```